# deploy cloud functions using cloud build failed: Error: failed to get firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

=== Deploying to 'project_id'...

Step #1:

Step #1: I deploy functions

Step #1:

Step #1: Error: Failed to get Firebase project project_id. Please ensure the project exists and that your account has permission to access it.

This is the error I am getting when I try to deploy my cloud function using cloud build.

This is my `cloudbuild.yaml` steps:

```
#Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
  
#Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/flysample-75b81/firebase'
  args: ['deploy']
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If anyone has an idea, Let me know how to solve this error.

Comment: Have you already check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#configuring_the_deployment)? You're missing some flags on the `args`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Will you please let me know the sample cloudbuild file.
As I have tried so many options and none work for me

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#configuring_the_deployment),

> Create a build config file named cloudbuild.yaml or cloudbuild.json where project-id is your Cloud project ID and firebase-project-id is your Firebase project ID

You should specify your Firebase Project ID in the `.yaml` or `.json` file. See sample below:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/project-id/firebase
  args: ['deploy', '--project=firebase-project-id', '--only=hosting']
```